# Dynamic Programming Complexity Analysis

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, depth-first-search, memoization

The problem in question is Leetcode's https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-dice-rolls-with-target-sum/. My [initial approach](https://github.com/domfarolino/algorithms/blob/dice-rolls/src/algorithm_practice/Dynamic_Programming/diceRollsWithTargetSum/dice.cc) was a tree-recursive problem with memoization. The problem can be characterized by the three parameters `d`, `f`, and `t`. I break the problem of determining how many rolls are possible with `d` dice to roll target `t` by focusing on one die, which can (effectively) take on any value in the range `[1, t]`. My rationale is because `f` could be as large as `t`, and we don't need to consider `f` values > `t`; therefore `f = O(t)` effectively.

So for each `n in [1, min(f, t)]`, I make a recursive call to the subproblem characterized by `d - 1` die, and `t - n` target, simulating one die roll of value `n`. Eventually we reach the base case `d = 1`, and can store either `1` or `0` in our memo keyed by the pair `<d, t>`. For each problem, we'd sum up the subproblem solutions, and store the result in our memo and return it. This gives us a tree like the following:

[image: tree recursive]

So my question is: What is the time complexity of this algorithm?

Clearly we may touch at most every combination of `d` and `t`, making it `Omega(d*t)`. However, since for each problem we have to sum together `f = O(t)` sub problems, I think we must add another factor of `t` for a complexity of `O(d*t*t)` (More accurately `O(d*min(f, t)*t)`). Does this make sense?

Furthermore, this seems to corroborate the bottom-up solution, which works on a `d*t`-sized table, but for each problem must sum together all `f` subproblems, which I believe puts us at [`O(d*t*t)`](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-dice-rolls-with-target-sum/discuss/390340/Java-short-solution-DP-80-runtime-100-memory).

Comment: Did you subtract one too many from dice 2 to dice 3 in your image? Also, are you using the constraint that rolls larger than `target` need not be considered only in the initial node or also the later once? Your image suggests that you don't because you end up with `target = -1`.

Comment: Yes, your analysis of the algorithm makes sense.  You've missed a couple of edge cases (e.g. we require `d <= t <= d*f`), but they don't affect the complexity.  However, I'm wondering why you're worried about this at all.  Why not simply use the closed-form computation, which is **O(d)**?

Comment: @uneven_mark Yes that subtraction was a mistake, it's just a rough picture, good catch. The restriction I mentioned and the picture are just rough and high-level. I just  wanted to demonstrate as many nodes in the tree as possible; in the code (linked from the post) I only roll from [1, min(f, t)] in each frame.

Comment: @Prune Thanks for taking a look. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by `d <= t <= d*f`; there is no constraint like this in the Leetcode post, and the code I linked to considers all relevant edge cases (AC solution). Perhaps you're saying I was overly-general in my description of the bounds my algorithm will process, but yes I was just trying to be descriptive in the post, not very rigorous :). Not sure I see the closed-form computation you mention, feel free to elaborate on it as it is not obvious to me

Comment: Each remaining roll has a minimum value of `1` and a max of `f`; thus, the sum must be in the range [d*1, d*f]; if the target value is outside of that range, you should prune the branch.

Comment: Regarding the closed-form computation: the number of ways to reach a given total as the sum of `N` uniform distributions (e.g. roll of fair dice) is a well-known formula, a direct computation given the information you have for this problem.  You should be able to find it on line, or derive it inductively.  You need the binomial distribution.  For a simple D2 (i.e. coin flip), the formula produces Pascal's Triangle.